# Python: CSS Selector to use inside lxml.cssselect

Tags: python, css, css-selectors, lxml

I am trying to parse the given below html code using `lxml.html` and using `CSSSelector` instead of `XPath`.

```
link = doc.cssselect('html body div.results dl dt a)
```

the above code is giving me `content-1` and `content-2` as output but my desired output is `link 1 link 2`. So I replaced my code with

```
link = doc.cssselect('html body div.results dl dt a[href]')
```

but still am getting the same output. So my question is what's the proper CSS selector to get href attribute.

```
             <div class = "results">
                     <div> some tags here </div>
                        <dl> 
                              <dt title = "My Title 1" style = "background: transparent url('/img/accept.png') no-repeat right center">
                              <a href = "/link 1"> content-1</a> 
                              </dt>
                       </dl>

                      <dl>
                             <dt title = "My Title 2" style = "background: transparent url('/img/accept.png') no-repeat right center">
                             <a href = "/link 2">content-2</a>
                             </dt>
                     </dl>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I *believe* you cannot get the attribute value through CSS selectors. You should get the elements...

```
>>> elements = doc.cssselect('div.results dl dt a')
```

...and then get the attributes from them:

```
>>> for element in elements:
...     print element.get('href')
... 
/link 1
/link 2
```

Of course, list comprehensions are your friends:

```
>>> [element.get('href') for element in elements]
['/link 1', '/link 2']
```

Since you cannot update properties of attributes in CSS, I believe there is no sense on getting them through CSS selectors. You can "mention" attributes in CSS selectors to retrieve only to match their elements. <del>However, is is just cogitation and I may be wrong; if I am, please someone correct me :)</del> Well, @Tim Diggs confirms my hypothesis below :)

Comment: @brandizzi, you're right - you can only select elements in css, not attributes -- the brackets are for filtering which elements to select (but not a bad idea to select only <a> tags without href attributes (which is what a[href] does).

Comment: @RanRag, you should tick brandizzi's answer as correct even if you didn't need it in the end.

Comment: i was going to tick it but you can only accept an answer after a certain period of time( i believe its arnd 5 mins)

Comment: For anyone coming to this later, you CAN get the attribute value through CSS selectors (using a psuedo-selector).  `doc.cssselect('div.results dl dt a::attr(href)')`

Comment: @Singletoned oooh, that's cool! Yet I could not get it to work with lxml and cssselect. When I tried it with lxml 4.9.2 ([the most recent I've found](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/tags)) I got the error `cssselect.xpath.ExpressionError: Pseudo-elements are not supported.` Am I missing something? Is this supported on an unreleased version of lxml? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the attribute on the result of cssselect (it always returns the element, never an attribute):

firstly, I'm not sure about doc.cssselect (but maybe this is your own function?)

lxml.cssselect is normally used:

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
sel = CSSSelector('html body div.results dl dt a[href]')
```

then, assuming you've already got a doc

```
links = []
for a_href in sel(doc):
    links.append(a_href.get('href'))
```

or the more succinct:

```
links = [a_href.get('href') for a_href in doc.cssselect('html body div.results dl dt a[href]')]
```

Comment: basically doc is equivalent to `doc=lxml.html.fromstring(content)` where content is my html data  from `urllib and read` functions

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully used

```
#element-id ::attr(value)
```

To get the "value" attribute for HTML  elements.

Answer (score 0):

lxml cssselector works with attributes selection. Below code can select src attribute from HTML script element.

```
   select = cssselect.CSSSelector("script[src]")
   links = [ el.get('src') for el in select(dochtml) ]
   links=iter(links)
   for n, l in enumerate(links):
       print n, l
```